# Do I have to implement an application on the ble-gateway side also?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, router, gateway

If I want to connect my ble device to a ble-gateway and communicate with a specific server via tcp, do I have to implement an application on the ble-gateway side also myself?
I need to send/receive raw data with a custom gatt service to/from the server.

Thanks,
Calvin

Comment: What is your ble-gateway?

Comment: It will be CASSIA E1000.  https://www.cassianetworks.com/products/e1000-bluetooth-edge-router/

Comment: Based on the deocumentation provided by Cassian my understanding is that you indeed have to implement something to access your custom service. Have a look at this: https://github.com/CassiaNetworks/CassiaSDKGuide/wiki

Comment: Thank you very much M. Kotzjan, One more question, Is there any appropriate standard gatt profile(service) for send/receive raw data? (Even though I know that SPP does not exist)

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37981606/7473793
There is no standard, but your ble device might offer a UART service